# debian 7 apache 2.4 как это сделать?

Tags: apache, debian

Ребята собственно вопрос, есть сервер к сожалению из-за платформы я не могу установить ubuntu 14 стоить читая debian 7 amd64.

Сразу говорю я турок именно в debian, могу еще centOS поставить там я еще большая блондинка он еще сложнее, ubuntu просто не ставится и все.

## uname -a

Linux 34612-dedic-admin 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.78-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

## lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.10 (wheezy)
Release:    7.10
Codename:   wheezy

проблема:
Дебиан как убунта, там все просто ставить пакеты я умею и репозитории добавлять и настраивать эти сервера которые я описал но я собственно не знаю какие репозитории нужны для того чтобы поставить сервера нужных мне версий!

apt-get install apache2 ставит apache2.22 мне надо 2.4 вообще в идеале мне надо:

**apache 2.4**

пробовал скачать deb пакет но

## dpkg -i apache2_2.4.20-1_amd64.deb

dpkg: regarding apache2_2.4.20-1_amd64.deb containing apache2, pre-dependency problem:
 apache2 pre-depends on dpkg (>= 1.17.14)
  dpkg is installed, but is version 1.16.17.

dpkg: error processing apache2_2.4.20-1_amd64.deb (--install):
 pre-dependency problem - not installing apache2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apache2_2.4.20-1_amd64.deb

собсвенно ругается что версия не та.

Comment: вопрос по поводу медленной записи лучше вынести отдельно: он никак не связан с первыми двумя из заданных. да и первые два, вероятно, лучше разнести: отдельно про apache, отдельно про nginx.

Comment: по поводу новых версий: наиболее разумным мне представляется обновление системы до текущей stable-версии. система в данный момент для чего-то используется?

Comment: Спасибо убрал вопросы которое менее приоритетные. Но все же вот зачем мне debian 8 там другая уже система я ее не знаю вообще. Учить можно но сейчас вопрос именно такой debian 7 и apache 2.4

Comment: да та же самая система. только версии многих программ (но далеко не всех) более новые. но если не хотите обновлять, то выхода два: 1. продолжать искать пакеты, собранные для вашей версии дистрибутива, 2. собрать самостоятельно.

Comment: Ясно, тогда если вы считаете переход с 7 на 8 уместным напишите пожалуйста приимущества - ответом. Я сейчас попробую все обновить. Думаю вы правы я получу производительность а вы еще немножко к репутации :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте проинсталлировать нужный пакет с помощью [gdebi](https://packages.debian.org/ru/wheezy/gdebi). Это программа, разрешающая зависимости при установке пакета.

полностью удаляем текущие пакеты Apache:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache*
```

Обновляем список пакетов:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Устанавливаем gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Устанавливаем нужный вам пакет:

```
sudo gdebi apache2_2.4.20-1_amd64.deb
```